# Exploring NLP Techniques for Transforming Web Content into Engaging Q&A Formats

Tags: natural-language-processing, question-answering

I'm looking for innovative methods or tools that leverage natural language processing (NLP) to transform web content into an interactive Q&A format. NLP has gotten so good that I no longer program (NLP) with my hands, and I believe it can make online content more engaging, akin to the programmed learning approach used in books like Quick Calculus and Little Schemer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_learning).

Current experiments with large language models (LLMs) to generate questions and answers have shown limitations:

- Tedious manual copy-pasting
- Token limitations
- Irrelevant or unhelpful questions
- Loss of original formatting
- Potential hallucinations

I'm seeking an NLP-based solution with the following characteristics:

- User-friendly, preferably as a browser extension
- Quick activation via click or keyboard shortcut
- No token limit
- Generation of meaningful questions
- Integration of questions with corresponding answers
- Preservation of the original webpage's appearance
- Use of existing text for answers

Based on previous suggestions, I've considered an approach that involves:

1. Extracting webpage text using [Mozilla's Readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability)
2. Generating questions with Haystack's [QuestionGenerator](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/question_generator)
3. Locating answers using Haystack's [Reader](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/reader)
4. Inserting questions and answers into the webpage's DOM

However, I'm eager to explore alternative ideas and techniques. Are there other NLP-powered tools or methodologies that could effectively accomplish this objective? I appreciate any insights or recommendations!